# how to compare rows in dplyr grouped data?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to compare x2 and x3 columns in grouped (grouped by ID) dataset. I want to compare x2 and x3 in rows where the first 1 appears in column x1. if x2 is greater than x3, I will assign 1 to ID and otherwise 0. Please see the example below. My input data is dt, in this dataset,  first appears 1 in the column x1 for the ID 100 is the 2nd row and  1410 < 1510, so I will assign 0 to ID 100. first appears 1 in the x1 column for the ID 101 is the 6th row and it is seen that 1500 > 1000, so I will assign 1 to ID 101. you can see my output as ot below. Thanks

```
dt<-data.frame(ID=c(100, 100,100, 101, 101, 101), 
               x1=c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0,1), 
               x2=c(1100, 1410, 1900, 1300, 1100, 1500),
               x3=c(1400, 1510, 2900, 300, 100,1000))

ot<-data.frame(ID=c(100,101), res=c(0,1))
```

Comment: Is `1500 < 1000` ?

Comment: I changed, thanks @AnilGoyal

Comment: Or here, Please consider to accept soluitons if it works. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `tidyverse` approaches for this.  Grouped by 'ID', `slice` the rows where the 'x1' is `max`, then `summarise` with integer converted relational expression (can also use `mutate`, but `summarise` drops the last group by default and as there is only a single group - we don't need to `ungroup` again)

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    slice(which.max(x1)) %>%
    summarise(res =  +(x2 > x3))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#     ID   res
#  <dbl> <int>
#1   100     0
#2   101     1
```

---

Or another option is to order the rows by 'ID' and a logical expression on 'x1' i.e. where x1 is 0, then grouped by 'ID', `summarise` with the relational expression constructed with `first` values of 'x2' and 'x3'

```
dt %>%
   arrange(ID, !x1) %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   summarise(res = +(first(x2) > first(x3)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#     ID   res
#  <dbl> <int>
#1   100     0
#2   101     1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use -

```
library(dplyr)

dt %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(res = {
    tmp <- match(1, x1)
    as.integer(x2[tmp] > x3[tmp])
})
```

`match` would return the 1st index where 1 is present in `x1`. We compare the value of `x2` and `x3` at that position and return 1 if `x2 > x3` or 0 otherwise.

Comment: fab strategy.  This creating of invisible objects I have to learn.  Upvoted Ronak :)